# Cookie notice coming in the top of the html page : Magento2

Tags: magento2, extensions, seo, cookie, third-party-module

> i have installed https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-cookie-notice.html
>   cookie extension in my website .

Now i am facing a serious issue .

> In my page source this cookies content is coming before my page
>   content . As the result google taking cookies content as page content
>   and displayed in search result .
>
> If i fill the meta description google taking that meta description ,
>   but if i forget to fill meta description google taking cookie content
>   (By continuing to use this site you agree to our use of cookies) as
>   page content.
>
> So when i type my website in google i can see the page title , url and
>   cookie content .

How can i solve this ?

Comment: You need to check the extension code which is adding meta content on the website.

Comment: there is any good cookie extension that place code only in the footer of page

Comment: OK, let me check and revert get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the below free extensions for the Cookie Compliance.

> https://magecomp.com/magento-2-cookie-compliance.html
>
> https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-cookie-notice-extension.html

**Hope it helps!!!**